# Forwarding subdomain to a port of localhost using WHM and apache2

Tags: apache, docker, dns, reverse-proxy, whm

In brief, I can access my site using `example.com:3000` but I want to access it using `sub.example.com`.

I am using WHM to manage my server using the `example.com` domain. I have added a **DNS Zone** using the WHM control panel for `sub.example.com`. It works fine and redirects to `sub.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi`.

I also tried to make a reverse proxy using ***VirtualHost*** by adding the following lines to the `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file as mentioned in [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/857680/port-to-subdomain-in-apache):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I restarted the Apache server using `sudo systemctl restart httpd`. However the subdomain still redirects to the `sub.example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` path rather than forwarding to the `port:3000`. Could you please help me resolve this problem?

It is worth mentioning that the server is using WHM and CPanel (version 84.0.21) on CentOS (version 7.7) as well as Apache (version 2.4.41) and the  `port:3000` is connected to a docker image (gitea) via docker-compose.

Comment: Temporarily this can be solved by redirecting the subdomain to that port.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the same setup and was able to solve it by using this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost sub.example.com:80>

    ServerName sub.example.com
    ServerAlias sub.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Adding it to Apache's include directive in WHM:
https://docs.cpanel.net/whm/service-configuration/include-editor/

For SSL port 443 you have to use the IP instead of domain:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443>
```